# Using RegEx with Notepad ++ for Mass Replacements

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have an xml file, where the code below repeats a few hundred times. I need to remove all instances of where Block Name="ZG123CZ123". Instead of having the remove start on the line where the app name condition is met, it needs to start at `<device>` and end at `</device>` for complete removal of where app condition is met. How exactly would I go about in doing this using Notepad ++ RegEx replacements?

```
<Device DevID="14212111" Model="" GroupID="">
  <Block Name="DG" LastFileDld="" LastFullDld="">
    <Group ZD="3">
      <DSize ParamName="*UNZIP" Value="DG.ZIP"/>
      <DSize ParamName="*GO" Value="F:DG.OUT"/>
    </Group>
    <Group ZD="15">
      <DSize ParamName="#LOGPORT" Value="NONE"/>
      <DSize ParamName="CDH6" Value=""/>
    </Group>
  </Block>
  <DevFiles />
</Device>
<Device DevID="14212111" Model="" GroupID="">
  <Block Name="ZG123CZ123" LastFileDld="" LastFullDld="">
    <Group ZD="1">
      <DSize ParamName="KEY" Value="RAM"/>
      <DSize ParamName="REM" Value="***"/>
      <DSize ParamName="*UNZIP" Value="I:ZG123CZ123.ZIP"/>
    </Group>
    <Group ZD="15">
      <DSize ParamName="REM" Value="="***""/>
      <DSize ParamName="#DEBUGPORT" Value=""/>
    </Group>
  </Block>
  <DevFiles />
</Device>
```

Comment: Can you test replacing `(?s)<Device(?:(?!<\/Device).)*<Block[^>]+Name="ZG123CZ123".*?<\/Device>` (http://regex101.com/r/bU5zC1/1) with nothing before I answer it (I don't have a build of N++ to try)?

Comment: Sam, this works flawlessly on my test. Checking what you did exactly now.

Comment: I'll post as an answer with an explanation :)

Comment: Can there be nested Devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this:**

```
(?s)<Device(?:(?!<\/Device).)*<Block[^>]+Name="ZG123CZ123".*?<\/Device>
```

<sub>[*Demo*](http://regex101.com/r/bU5zC1/1)</sub>

---

**Explanation:**

- `(?s)` is the single-line modifier, which makes `.` include newline characters.
- `<Device` looks for the beginning of a `Device` element.
- `(?:(?!<\/Device).)*` is essentially `.*`, but each time we try to match a character we make sure we aren't matching the end of a `Device` element (`<\/Device`) by using a negative lookahead. Note that you can't just make this a lazy match, since it would continue until if found the `<Block Name="ZG123CZ123">` (that is the next chunk).
- `<Block[^>]+Name="ZG123CZ123"` will look for the beginning of a `Block` element, followed by non `>` character(s), followed by the `Name` attribute equaling `ZG123CZ123`.
- `.*?` is a lazy match to eat up the rest of the `Device` element.
- `<\/Device>` we've made it to the end!

Comment: thanks so much, i was a little confused on how the 3rd and 4th bullet points worked, but makes much more sense now. adding this to my notes.